# MS Access: Display multiple specific records on one form (not using multiple items)

Tags: ms-access

tldr: I want to create a form where specific fields from specific records are displayed based on filters or parameters. I do not want to use a subform or multiple item form.

the context: I am creating a database with information about different countries. My table Indicators (picture 1) contains country names, indicators names (e.g. Population, GDP, ...) and the respective values. I will collect data on the same indicators for every country. 
I want to create a form where I can select a country, and then display the values of the indicators are for that country (picture 2).
I do not want to use a multi item form, because I want to create a visually appealing layout.

I have made a sketch of my data table

[image]

And the form I want to create

[image]

**EDIT:** Actually the form should look more like this, i.e. **not a tabular layout**.
[image]

I would be greatful for any suggestions how to build such a form.

Comment: Are you happy to get the data in a recordset and write to every required textbox? It will be quite tedious returning edits to the database. Also, When you look at your layout, it is not so very different from a continuous form, a little formatting and you would be very close.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the form wizard to generate a simple data-bound form from your table. Then you can change it to show one record at a time, make all the controls read-only, and add a combo box to select the country and add a little VBA event handler to the combo box so that whenever its selection changes, the form navigates to the record for that country. Of course, in a form you can customise the layout to show indicators in any style you want. So this approach should fulfill all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With very little effort, I can get the following form and subform:

[image: Form and subform]

A little more tampering with the layout, and you can have exactly what you want.

To fill in various boxes, you can use DlookUp and you can use a recordset to write to your textboxes, but it is all quite messy.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That would be a possible solution. However, I prefer not to have a tabular data sheet layout, but to arrange the items freely (See edit in my question). Is there a way to specify a different data source (e.g. an SQL query) for each individual text box? I intend to use the form mostly for displaying the data, not for editing it.

Comment: Wow, DLookup is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks.